# Firebase: Fetching data form firebase firestore db

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-context

I'm looking for a decent data fetching approach in nextjs which i can use in my app. In my firestore db i have users documents so i need to fetch auth user data after its successfull auth process and than use that data across few components (profile modal, navbar). Currently i made sth like that just to make it work.

useFetchUsers

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

import { db } from "../utils/firebase";

export const useFetchUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));

    const data = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      data.push({ ...doc.data() });
    });

    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchUsers();
      setUsers(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { users, loading };
};
```

A component where i need auth user data

```
 const { users, loading } = useFetchUsers();
  const [currentUserUid, setCurrentUserUid] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUserUid(user.uid);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const currentUser = useMemo(
    () => users.filter((user) => user.uid === currentUserUid),
    [currentUserUid, users]
  );
```

I was thinking of creating a context with onAuthStateChange logic and then share it across my components

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Any error message?

Comment: It works but I’m looking for better solutions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using React-Query, it’s a fetching library for the react ecosystem, making your life simpler when it comes to data fetching, mutation, and the general life state of your data.

```
export const useGetUsers = () => {
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'users'));

    const data = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      data.push({ ...doc.data() });
    });

    return data;
  };

  return useQuery('get-users', fetchUsers);
};
```

You can then use it this way in your component

```
function Component() {
    const {data} = useGetUsers()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn’t fully solve my problem

Comment: Anyway query is useless here since i want to fetch data only once in context and then extract only auth user and then reuse it